# A list of downloaded files is null

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to get a list of downloaded files, here's code in Kotlin:

```
val dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
val files = dir.listFiles()
```

I have  files in the folder but this code returns null. How come?

Comment: do you have the correct permissions?

Comment: Did you update Android media something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the permission to read from external storage.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```